# Encode or Hide URL

Tags: php, html, apache, url, iframe

We have a member administration system that as been developed over about 5 years so redesigning it is not possible, so my question is what is the best why to encode or hide the url parameters from users? I currently added our whole website in a iframe like below for the time being?

```
<iframe id="my-iframe-tag" onload="autoResize('my-iframe-tag'); parent.scrollTo(0,0); window.parent.$(body).animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');" name="my-iframe-tag" src="MY-URL" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Is there anything we can set on the web server or what is the best way to do this? Our pages

Comment: Just curious... why? (Btw, do you mean the query string in the URL in the src-tag?)

Comment: For the browser to use the url it has to be able to read it

Comment: The iframe is just for the time being we would like to encode the browser URL with a function of some sorts, I just added the frame code as that is what we are using now to get around hiding the URL.